# I can't edit the links on html and css

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.backdrop {
  background: url(../images/header.JPG) center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 185px;
  width: 85vw;
}

.text {
  text-shadow: 0 0 9px white;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid;
  background: rgb(59, 2, 6);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  font: bolder 10vw 'arial';
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  animation: glow 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes glow {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  }
  15% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), -2px -2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  30% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7), -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  }
  ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
  li a {
    color: #544738;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 12px;
  }
  li a:hover {
    color: #7eb9be;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Julian Mancera- Final Project</title>
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>



<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="backdrop">
      <p class="text">Julian Mancera</p>
    </div>

    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm making my first website for school and I am a little stuck because I am a beginner. I wanted to use this method to create a nav bar, but it didn't work.

https://designshack.net/articles/css/creating-a-fun-animated-navigation-menu-with-pure-css/

I even tried to edit the links, but they don't even change of color...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDXur.jpg)

Here is the picture with the links.

Comment: if add your html and css codes i can help you.

Comment: @DogukanCavus  I am new here, and this website doesn't let me to paste the code here. Is there any other way I can contact you?? so i can show you the pics??? please?

Comment: @JuliánCMancera when you're inside the editor, press CTRL + M (or the icon that looks like a file with brackets, to the right of the image icon). You can paste your code in the given sections.

Comment: you can adding code easy. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc8nZ.png

Comment: @DogukanCavus so basically I want to apply this to my website but i cant do it!

Comment: @DogukanCavus  https://designshack.net/articles/css/creating-a-fun-animated-navigation-menu-with-pure-css/

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd just missed a closing `}` when closing off the styling for `@keyframes glow {`. The code below works (I haven't imported the custom font).

```css
body{
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.backdrop {
  background: url(../images/header.JPG) center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 185px;
  width: 85vw;  
}
    

ul li {
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 margin-right: 1em; 
}
 
li a {
 color: #544738;
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding: 12px;
}
 
li a:hover {
 color: #7eb9be;
}
    

.text {
  text-shadow: 0 0 9px white;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid;
  background: rgb(59, 2, 6);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  font: bolder 10vw 'arial';
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  animation: glow 3s infinite;
}


li a:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
 -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
}

.left a:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
 -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
}
 
.right a:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
 -moz-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
 -o-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
}


.left a:hover {
 
 /*Transition*/ 
 -webkit-transition:All .5s ease;
 -moz-transition:All .5s ease;
 -o-transition:All .5s ease;
 
 /*Transform*/ 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
 -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
}
 
.right a:hover {
 
 /*Transition*/ 
 -webkit-transition:All .5s ease;
 -moz-transition:All .5s ease;
 -o-transition:All .5s ease;
 
 /*Transform*/ 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
 -moz-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
 -o-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
}

@keyframes glow {
    0% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
    }
    15% {
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
                   -2px -2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    }
    30% {
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7),
                   -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Julian Mancera- Final Project</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
  

    
<body>
  <div id="container">
  <div class="backdrop">
  <p class="text">Julian Mancera</p>
  </div>

      
      
<ul id="nav">
 <li class="left"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li class="right"><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li class="left"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
 <li class="right"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
    
    
    
    
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Styling links in css with the :link pseudo classes. Ex.

```
a:link {
color: pink;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were just missing a `}` after the keyframes!
This would cause the keyframes style to not close correctly, and the following styles would fail. Those styles just happened to be your links.

Something that may help you in your assignments is a good IDE to program in; one that will highlight errors like that one for you. I'd suggest [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), it's very good and very free.

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.backdrop {
  background: url(../images/header.JPG) center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 185px;
  width: 85vw;
}
   
.text {
  text-shadow: 0 0 9px white;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid;
  background: rgb(59, 2, 6);
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
  font: bolder 10vw 'arial';
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  animation: glow 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes glow {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  }
  15% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
                 -2px -2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  30% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7),
                 -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  }
}
    
ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 1em; 
}
 
li a {
  color: #544738;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 12px;
}
 
li a:hover {
  color: #7eb9be;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Julian Mancera- Final Project</title>
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
  
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="backdrop">
      <p class="text">Julian Mancera</p>
    </div>

    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Oliver and Pat...
it's funny how much havoc a little bracket can cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have added custom CSS. Please check and let us know.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.backdrop {
  background: url(../images/header.JPG) center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 185px;
  width: 85vw;
}

.text {
  text-shadow: 0 0 9px white;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid;
  background: rgb(59, 2, 6);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  font: bolder 10vw 'arial';
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  animation: glow 3s infinite;
}
ul { margin-top: 50px; }
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
ul li a:hover { color: #ccc; } 
ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding: 20px; 
}
ul li {
 -webkit-transition: All .5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: All .5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: All .5s ease-in-out;
 transition: All .5s ease-in-out;
}
ul li:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
 -moz-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
 -o-transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
 transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
}

ul li:nth-child(even):hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
-moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
-o-transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(1.2);
}

@keyframes glow {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  }
  15% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), -2px -2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  30% {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7), -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  }
  ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
  li a {
    color: #544738;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 12px;
  }
  li a:hover {
    color: #7eb9be;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="backdrop">
      <p class="text">Julian Mancera</p>
    </div>

    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```